Unsubscribe link is not forming in outlook
I  have created a calendar invite notification for change task and using a a template 'change.calendar.integration' which has following content:
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Service-now.com//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:${to}
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:${from}
Activity due: ${activity_due}
DTSTART:${dtstart}
DTEND:${dtend}
LOCATION:${location}
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:${sys_mod_count}
UID:${number}
DTSTAMP:${dtstamp}
DESCRIPTION:${description}Click Here${unsubscribe_link}
SUMMARY:${summary}
PRIORITY:3
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:${priority}
STATUS:CONFIRMED
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

I want to add unsubscribe link in the received calendar invite. I have used {$notif_unsub} in the html body but it is showing in html form not as "Unsubscribe" link .
